# Is it possible to specify a URI to a pdf that points to a specific page?

Tags: windows, uri

I'm specifically curious about Windows, but answers about different OS are interesting too.

Afaik in URLs a specific PDF page can be indicated by adding a `#page=<page number>` field. According to the URI specification, fields (using the `#<field>` syntax) and queries (using the `?<key>=<value>` syntax) should be possible. However, URIs of the form `file:///path_to_document.pdf#page=20` or `file:///path_to_document.pdf?page=20` didn't work for me, Windows is interpreting the whole string as a path, which it then can't find.

Is there any way to accomplish this? I couldn't find anything online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling files from the Operating System there are rules that are system based. So calling a file from OS needs a certain syntax, that needs quoting for some characters, so these work, whatever the default PDF handler may be:-
[image]

That default handler may include a different page switch syntax such as exe -page ## filename.

[image]

When using a URL you need a URL handler, so this will work in Windows

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" "file:///C:/Apps/PDF/poppler/%2333.pdf#page=20"
```

The URL can be on a LAN server and windows will often fiddle with the usage of \ and / but not aways accept both. So the rule is "use quotes" AND replace system punctuation with safe characters AND ensure "Remember last page" is not active.

[image]

The use of `#` fragments for PDF navigation was introduced by Adobe for their Acrobat plug-in and has in parts been adopted by some browser plug-ins . So some work one way in Chrome  but some can be different name or behaviour in FireFox, so beware which browser you use as default.

One example is `#search=` works well in FireFox but is totally different in Chromium. #:~:text=Chromium but does not work with PDF nor this page !

In comments you mentioned Obsidian which is a closed product (not open source for easy modifications). What I found is it need an object per link thus in the vault you would need to use a window.lnk file as the shim from internal to external calling

[image]

in the vault it would be

```
Open 3pages.pdf @ page 2 [page 2 of 3Pages.pdf](file:///C:%5CApps%5CPIM%5CObsidian%5C3Pages.pdf%20-%20Shortcut.lnk)
```

externally the shortcut could be

```
"C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -page 2 C:\Apps\PIM\Obsidian\vault\3Pages.pdf
```

As I tested this workaround each link would be a highly wasteful 4Kb of disk space, so there are perhaps better ways to call 1 file with 2 arguments, which works in many cases as a "Shim", however there are open source plug-ins that are perhaps close enough to adapt see https://github.com/MichalBures/obsidian-file-path-to-uri

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I checked this, and it works in the terminal, so I'm gonna accept this as an answer.
However, the reason I asked this in the first place is that I wanted to use these URIs in Obsidian. And there, it does not work. For some reason, here, the `page=xx` part is interpreted as part of the path, and it throws a file not found error. Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Wow, thanks for going through all of that. If I understand correctly though, that `shortcut.lnk` file is static, meaning I would have to have a different shortcut file for each page number I would want to open?
And yeah, I already raised a bug report with Obsidian ...

Comment: got you, thanks. I also think it's not really worth it to dig deeper. Either I write a script that  creates these .lnk files to the specified page automatically, or I wait for Obsidian to iplement this properly